# JPA 1.0 @OrderBy uses field names vs. JPA 2.0 @OrderColumn uses column names

Tags: jpa, sql-order-by, jpa-2.0

According to the Java EE 6 docs JPA 1.0 `@OrderBy` uses field names vs. JPA 2.0 `@OrderColumn` uses column names when declaring the annotations. See here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html

The former is available since JPA 1.0, the latter was added with JPA 2.0. If you read the docs for a moment it becomes clear that `@OrderBy` uses fields/properties to specify the order, whereas `@OrderColumn` takes an SQL/DDL column name.

Why has it been made that way? To me this looks plain inconsistent.

Is there a deeper point why things have been made that way? Is it a JPA 1.0 relic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to understand the difference between an ordered list (JPA1, JPA2), and an indexed list (JPA2). One orders the elements by a condition, and the other preserves the position they were inserted at. They fulfil different use-cases. OrderColumn allows specification of a column name for schema generation purposes. OrderBy provides a query mechanism for retrieval purposes. Consequently what the annotations and XML allow input of are different.

Comment: Well, that's what I understand: the ordered list can be ordered by any fields, not just integers. But why does `@OrderBy` need fields and doesn't use column names? I can see this wouldn't make sense for `@OrderColumn`. Both need to go to the DB via SQL, so why go the intermediate route for `@OrderBy` using field names? Hmmm... I don't really get it.

Comment: OrderColumn adds an index column. That is not present with OrderBy. OrderBy doesn't allow the original ordering to be retained, since it has no such index

Comment: Yes for sure, but does that answer why the one expects **field names** instead of **SQL column names**, which is the whole question? Couldn't `@OrderBy` have used column names? Why was it made that way? It's that simple. I still don't understand it.

Comment: Why would an object-based API use datastore (column) names ? This is not an SQL replacement. The developer is working with classes and specifying that his/her classes have a field ordered using this other field of the other class. If you want to use SQL all over the place then just use JDBC

Comment: You contradict yourself: "Why would an object-based API use datastore (column) names?" Because `@OrderColumn` does? That's the whole point of my question and many other annotations like `XToX` use column names, too, so your argument isn't a good one. I have no idea why such a simple question can cause so much trouble.

Comment: No contradiction there. OrderColumn allows the user to specify the column name of the surrogate index column in the datastore, in the same way as Column allows the user to set the column name that a field is persisted to (i.e schema info). OrderBy is a query mechanism, hence uses field names just like JPQL does